# Max size of "name" attribute when posting?

Tags: php, apache, drupal-7

I am using a Drupal webform that works on my local machine, but not on the server. Most of the fields work, but for about 4 of them, Drupal complains that they were not filled in, even though they were.

The only thing I can see that looks strange for the one's failing, is that the "name" attribute is huge. So my theory is that the server running Centos 6 (apache with cPanel) has some kind of limit on the size of a variable that gets posted to the server.

See the code generated by google:

```
<textarea required="required" id="edit-submitted-are-you-currently-offering-service-and-support-for-any-products-you-sell" name="submitted[are_you_currently_offering_service_and_support_for_any_products_you_sell]" cols="60" rows="5" class="form-textarea required error"></textarea>
```

So my theory is that this part is too long:

```
name="submitted[are_you_currently_offering_service_and_support_for_any_products_you_sell]"
```

Any idea if there is such a limit? Or perhaps something else could cause it?

**UPDATE**

When I make the fields shorter, it works. So there is something blocking this. I've checked:

- Apache logs
- error_log
- mod_security log

Out of ideas, but will keep looking.

Comment: Have you tried to rename your fields with shorter names in order to confirm your theory?

Comment: Is this a GET or POST submit? GET request definitely have limits in total request size.

Comment: This is a POST. And yes, I can try to rename the fields, but don't want to go through all the forms on the site if I can just fix it for everyone in one go by increasing the allowed maximum size of these variables. However, let me try and rename one variable and see what I get ... ie. to confirm my theory.

Comment: Confirmed... making the field shorter allows it work on the server.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to add this to php.ini:

```
[suhosin]
suhosin.get.max_name_length = 130 
suhosin.post.max_name_length = 130 
suhosin.request.max_varname_length = 130
```

Drupal allows a maximum size of 128 Characters, so technically 128 should work instead of 30, but I added an extra bit of buffer, just in case.